# Inner Join and filter by date not working throws Integrity constraint violation error

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to make an inner join on two tables to get data. and it worked however when I search to get date from the table. I get an error saying

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in where clause 
is ambiguous, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales_flat_order` AS 
`main_table`
INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order_item` ON main_table.store_id = 
sales_flat_order_item.store_id WHERE (`created_at` >= '2017-04-01'
```

This is my code

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();

$collection->addFieldToFilter('created_at');
$collection->getSelect()->join("sales_flat_order_item", 
"main_table.store_id = sales_flat_order_item.store_id", 
array('name','sku','order_id','quantity'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
$collection->addFieldToFilter('main_table.created_at', '2017-04-01');
$collection->getSelect()->join("sales_flat_order_item",
    "main_table.store_id = sales_flat_order_item.store_id",
    array('name','sku','order_id','qty_ordered'));
```

But your join looks weird maybe it would be better to use sales_flat_order.entity_id = sales_flat_order_item.order_id then store_id

What exactly do you try to get by that select?

Please, describe your task.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

```
$startDate = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00", strtotime( date( "Y-m-d 00:00:00", 
strtotime( date("Y-m-d 00:00:00") ) ) . "-10 months" ) );
$endDate = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00", strtotime( date( "Y-m-d 00:00:00", 
strtotime( date("Y-m-d 00:00:00") ) ) . "+1 day" ) );
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $startDate, 'to' => $endDate)->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$this->setCollection($collection);
return parent::_prepareCollection();
```